# How to simulate Geolocation service AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, geolocation

I'm creating an app that is using Geolocation servioce on phone o send location/time data over the internet. And that is working just fine. Problem is that I cannot test it in Flashdevelop, cause Geolocation is not supported, so I have to upload every time new code and test it on phone. Is there any way to simulate Geolocation service in Flashdevelop? Or generally, on desktop PC?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bothering ... I found out... quite simple answer was..

```
private function startLocating():void {
    var myLat:Number=44.2343;
    var myLong:Number=20.9432;
    _geo = new Geolocation();
    _geo.addEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, Handler1 );
    if (Geolocation.isSupported) {
        if (!_geo.muted) {
            _geo.setRequestedUpdateInterval(1000);
        } else {
            trace ("Location service not turned on.");
        }
    } else {
        /* this code is working when Geolocation is not supported */
        _geo.dispatchEvent(new GeolocationEvent(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE,false,false,myLat,myLong));
    }
}
private function Handler1(ev:GeolocationEvent):void {
    var latitude:Number = ev.latitude;
    var longitude:Number = ev.longitude;
    .....
}
```